# Distribution of X-Y when X and Y are independent geometric

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, summation, transformation

$X$ and $Y$ are independent geometric distributions with parameter $p$. Find the distribution for $X-Y$

I am aware that there are many similar questions. My problem with this specific transformation is that I cannot solve the summation I end up with.

This is what I have done:

$$Z = X - Y$$
$$P(Z=z) = P(X-Y=z)$$
$$= \sum_{k=1}^\infty P(Y=k)P(X=z+k)$$
$$= \sum_{k=1}^\infty p(1-p)^{k-1} p(1-p)^{z+k-1}$$

Somehow the answer should be:

$$\frac{p(1-p)^{|z|}}{2-p} $$

How does this sum turn into this final solution? Or have I done a mistake in the previous steps. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Note that $z$ belongs to the set of all integers. There are two cases to consider when finding the distribution of $Z$: when $k\ge 1$ ( so that $z\ge 0$ ) and when $k\ge 1-z$ ( so that $z<0$ ). You have written the sum for the first case. Combining both cases you would get the final answer as given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $z \ge 0$,\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^\infty p(1-p)^{k-1} p(1-p)^{z+k-1} &= p^2\sum_{k=1}^\infty  (1-p)^{z+2k-2} \\
&=p^2(1-p)^z \sum_{k=1}^\infty ((1-p)^2)^{k-1}\\
&=\frac{p^2(1-p)^z}{1-(1-p)^2}\\
&=\frac{p^2(1-p)^z}{(2-p)p}\\
&=\frac{p(1-p)^z}{2-p}\end{align}